# Comisión con php y mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Hola a todos tengo una tabla usuario y una tabla cliente donde tengo un campo llamado total(haciendo referencia al total de la venta). lo que deseo es calcular la comisión de cada usuario , tengo este query pero solo me trae la comisión de solo los usuarios que han vendido , necesito que se reflejo un $0 en los demás usuarios en caso tal de que este aun no tenga ventas

PDTA solo me trae 2 usuarios en un ejemplo ya que esto son los que tienen ventas y lo que deseo es que me muestre todos los usuarios con comisión -> $0 en caso tal de que no tengan ventas aun

```
SELECT usuario.nombre , usuario.idusuario, 
cliente.usuario_id,(usuario.comision * cliente.prima_total )comision
FROM usuario
INNER JOIN 
cliente
ON 
cliente.usuario_id = usuario.idusuario
```

Comment: Puedo hacer suposiciones, porque tu pregunta esta incompleta.. tene en cuenta que no se que es cliente, no se que es usuario, ni se que quiere decir cada campo, con lo cual, solo puedo suponer tu problema.... los nombres de los campos no dicen nada...

Comment: Ya logre hacer la consulta efectivamente me sale null en los dems campos como cambio eso por un 0 ? SELECT 
(u.comision * c.prima_total)
FROM usuario u LEFT JOIN cliente c  ON c.usuario_id = u.idusuario @gbianchi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basado en tu consulta, y suponiendo que viene en cada campo, la cosa vendria asi:

```
SELECT usuario.nombre , usuario.idusuario, 
cliente.usuario_id,(usuario.comision * cliente.prima_total )comision
FROM usuario
LEFT JOIN 
cliente
ON 
cliente.usuario_id = usuario.idusuario
```

Porque left join? porque left join le dice a la base de datos que ponga todas las filas de la izquierda, aun si no se cumple la condicion de join. Con lo cual, con eso, va a traer todos los usuarios.

Ahora, tenemos que resolver mas problemas...

mostrar el campo usuario.idusuario y cliente.usuario_id no sirve para nada.. tienen el mismo valor... asi que mejor eliminar el que viene de cliente, ya que ese puede ser nulo.

Y luego, tenemos el problema de multiplicar por null, en el caso de que no haya datos en cliente.

En mysql, al multiplicar por null, da null... con lo cual, podemos hacer uso de la funcion [Coalesce](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce), la cual trae el primer valor que encuentre que no sea null...

asi que, volvemos a arreglar la consulta y quedaria asi:

```
SELECT 
    usuario.nombre, 
    usuario.idusuario, 
    COALESCE((usuario.comision * cliente.prima_total),0) comision
FROM 
    usuario
LEFT JOIN 
    cliente
ON 
    cliente.usuario_id = usuario.idusuario
```

Comment: Muchas gracias a funcionado correctamente